# get clean html from rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just wondering if there is any script that can clean number of files, something that is capable of removing all html comments from html file?

And the same things for rails, as we know in rails view we can use ruby

if ruby within **<%= %>** that ruby output wil be printed in html body

if ruby within **<% -%>** that ruby output will not be printed in html body

if something else that blank line will be printed

please correct me if I made mistake

So I need something that can recognize ruby code within view and change the wrong tag to correct one just in order to get clean and short html code

For summary

1. script or idea for removing html comment from html
2. script or idea for replacing inappropriate ruby tag to appropriate one

Thanks!

Comment: actually it turns out that **mod_ext_filter of apache** is a good solution but only good not the right one, because it can be very overloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with vi / vim editor( powerful editor in linux ), you can use regex matching to find a replace the html comments.

Comment: vim is a great solution, but only for few files, I need something that can deal with bunch of files, and vim hardly can help me with wrong tags in rails